# Websocket push with php taking too long

Tags: php, websocket, push, phpwebsocket

I'm running a websocket server made with php (Ratchet http://socketo.me/) that is working fine when i connect with javascript native API. But when I try to make a push to the server using php it just take too long (10 seconds or more!).

Ratchet does not provide (as far as I know) any method to make a push with its native API, so im using this one: https://github.com/Textalk/websocket-php

The request is very simple:

```
//...

//Insert data into database ...

//Push data to the server, so the other clients get updated
$data = json_encode($requestData);
$client = new \WebSocket\Client("ws://localhost:10000");
$client->send($data); //<--10 sec request :(

//...
```

I took a look in the client code and added some lines (for testing purposes only):

```
stream_set_blocking($this->socket, 0);
```

and

```
$client->setTimeout(1);
```

But doesn't seems to work. Any help  will be very appreciated.

Comment: Did you try telnetting it? This would at least show if the responsivity loss is on server or client side.

Comment: carloscarucce@svrdev001:/$ telnet localhost 10000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost. @syck . its working fine...

Comment: The problem is that it takes Ratchet itself at least 6 seconds to fully establish an incoming connection, even longer if there are multiple clients already connected and actively communicating, because Ratchet's loop is `sleep(1)` based, rather than waiting on a blocking socket. Your bottleneck is one line above where you think it is. (Well, your bottleneck is Ratchet, but that's not something you can control without replacing it.)

Comment: @Ghedipunk I made a small change to the client class that helped a lot: http://bit.ly/1WUim2I (in case you want to check it out...). This reduced hanshake time by 80% (from 10 ~ 30 to 5 seconds). But I still have the Ratchet problem though